# Enable/Disable Telerik asp.net combo box with dynamic ID from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, combobox, telerik

I am creating a web app in which I am using telerik components, I want to Enable/Disable the combobox from Javascript but the problem is my combobox is created during pageload, and I am not able to use the following code which I Get From telerik Q/A

```
var category = $find("<%= combo1.ClientID %>");
category.enable();
```

what is the possible way to enable disable components of telerik asp.net from javascript?

Comment: When you say that combobox is created during pageLoad, do you mean it's created in server-side page load event or in client-side page load event?

Comment: server side pageload event

Comment: Is the radcombobox  initially visible when page renders in the browser?

Comment: I have added an answer based on the assumption that radcombobox is initially visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find different ways to obtain reference to the Telerik client-side object in this documentation article: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/get-client-side-reference.

You can also use the OnClientLoad client event of combobox to get reference to its client object:

```html
<script>
function OnClientLoadHandler(sender)   {
    var combo;
    combo=sender;
}
</script>

<telerik:RadComboBox RenderMode="Lightweight" 
    ID="RadComboBox1" 
    runat="server" 
    OnClientLoad="OnClientLoadHandler" .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript like below. Note that any action you want to take on page controls in JavaScript must be in `pageLoad` client-side event or later, since before this event the controls on the aspx page have not been created.

The below snippet needs to go into your aspx page.
I have assumed that the id of the radcombobox in markup is `combo1`.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function  pageLoad() {
    var category = $find("<%= combo1.ClientID %>");
    //use any one of the following lines of code to disable radcombobox
    category.enable();
    category.set_enabled(false);
    }
</script>
```